# Android: recreate() doesn't clear EditTexts

Tags: android, android-activity

I'm actually using `recreate()` method to restart an Activity, but this method doesn't clear the EditTexts inside the Activity.

How can i solve this?

Comment: Can you post the code you use for reCreate

Comment: You shouldn't use `recreate()` method for that purpose. Use `edittext.setText("")` instead

Comment: @bigdestroyer I'm not using recreate() for just clearing EditTexts. I need to restart the activity, like if I open it for the first time. When I use recreate(), EditTexts inside the activity doesn't get empty, but other objects like Layouts that I modify during Runtime get back like before.

Answer (score 1):

If you just want to clear your EditText without recreate the entire activity, you should use setText() method to clear it properly.

Like this:

```
yourEditText.setText("");
```

Comment: I'm not using `recreate()` for just clearing EditTexts. I need to restart the activity, like if I open it for the first time. When I use `recreate()`, EditTexts inside the activity doesn't get empty, but other objects like Layouts that I modify during Runtime get back like before.

Sorry for bad english, I hope you understand.

Comment: Ok, you can recreate your activity as you wished and then check if EditText are still filled or empty:
if(!TextUtils.isEmpty(yourEditText.getText().toString().trim()) {
   // Non-empty
   yourEditText.setText("");
}

Comment: I dont want to check if it's filled, I want it empty. Maybe I should clear EditTexts before `recreate()`, but it looks..... meh..... I think that exists a better way.

Comment: Sure, you can clear them without checking, either before or after recreating the activity, your choice :)

Answer (score 0):

As per the [documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#recreate()) for `recreate`, the call to recreate Cause the Activity to be recreated with a new instance. This results in essentially the same flow as when the Activity is created due to a **configuration** change -- the current instance will go through its lifecycle to `onDestroy`() and a new instance then created after it.

So basically `recreate`() doesn't actually act the same way as totally recreating the activity.

For example: if you have any Fragments with `setRetainInstance(true)` they won't be recreated; merely paused and resumed.

One more catch with `recreate` API is it is supported from API Level 11 and Above. Hence, use of `recreate` is ok if your app is only targeting SDK level 11 and above.

Check if you are using the `setRetainInstance(true)` in your code.

You need to may be show more code to understand the specific problem!

Comment: My application is like a Client Manager. In my Add Client activity, i have to set Name, Age, Country, etc. When I save this client, I want to reload the Add Client activity full empty, so I can add the next client. Really sorry for bad english, I hope you understand.

Comment: I guess you need to show bit more code otherwise its hard for anyone to figure out what is wrong. share more code showing relevant parts of it so that issue can be tracked down